# C++ & Raw Input - raw->data.keyboard.VKey == VK_ESCAPE is the only virtual key that works

Tags: c++, raw-input

Note that I've tested only a few, but out of those, only `VK_ESCAPE` will work.

What I really want is `VK_LWIN` and `VK_RWIN`, but these don't work either: `VK_CONTROL`, `VK_LCONTROL`, `VK_MENU`, `VK_F1`

I don't understand why none of those will work but `VK_ESCAPE` will work.

Here is the summarized code:

```
case WM_INPUT:
{
    LPBYTE lpb = new BYTE[dwSize];
    PRAWINPUT raw = (PRAWINPUT)lpb;
    UINT Event;

    Event = raw->data.keyboard.Message;
    keyChar = MapVirtualKey( raw->data.keyboard.VKey, MAPVK_VK_TO_CHAR);
    delete[] lpb;

    if (Event == WM_KEYUP)
    {
        if (keyChar == VK_LWIN)
        {
            system("start c:\\windows\\notepad.exe"); // For debugging, temporary
        }
    }
    break;
```

The intended purpose of this is to do something when the user presses the windows key, in this case that 'something' is sending a different input such as ctrl+alt+end (which is my hotkey for Launchy). Using AutoHotkey to do this isn't an option for me. I'm on Windows 10 if that makes a difference.

I code for games and 3D software normally, this is all new to me.

Comment: `LPBYTE lpb = new BYTE[dwSize]; PRAWINPUT raw = (PRAWINPUT)lpb; UINT Event; Event = raw->data.keyboard.Message;`  Allocate a buffer, reinterpret it to be a struct, then read from it before doing anything else?  That reads like nonesense.  If it is the fault of the summary, please test your summary before posting it.  I am uncertain why a `new` would occur anywhere near a raw key handler at all, however.

Comment: @Yakk you're right, a lot of this is based off what I've found by googling and I've fixed up my code, but it doesn't solve the issue, however c-smile did solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need MapVirtualKey for that purpose.

I suspect that raw->data.keyboard.VKey is a virtual code. And VK_LWIN and VK_RWIN are virtual codes. Yet they do not have character representation so MapVirtualKey makes no sense for them. ESCAPE has character code in ASCII so it works in your case.

Thus your code should really look like:

```
case WM_INPUT:
{
    ...
    unsigned vkCode = raw->data.keyboard.VKey;

    if (Event == WM_KEYUP)
    {
        if (vkCode == VK_LWIN)
        {
            system("start c:\\windows\\notepad.exe"); // For debugging, temporary
        }
    }
    break;
```